# pass updated state to child when axios.get call after props changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass updated state to child component when props changed in parent  and axios.get request fetch data from server and state changed. I got first state in child but when after props changed, Parent state got updated but the updated state can not be passed to child component.

**ParentComponent**

```
export default class OverallProgress extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selectedCourseID: props.selectedCourseID,
        overallProgressData: null,
         blocking: true
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this._loadData(this.props.selectedCourseID);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({selectedCourseID: nextProps.selectedCourseID});
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.selectedCourseID !== prevProps.selectedCourseID) {
        this._loadData(this.props.selectedCourseID);
    }
}

_loadData(selectedCourseID) {
    axios.get('/userquery/getDataForWidgets?widget_id=' + this.props.widgetID + '&course_id=' + selectedCourseID)
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                overallProgressData: response.data,
                chartReportView: true,
                blocking: false
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert('Oops! Something went wrong. Please refresh the page and try again.');
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response);
            }
        });
}  render(){
     return(
        <div>
             <OverallProgressLineChart
                   data={this.state.overallProgressData}
                   selectedCourseID={this.state.selectedCourseID}
                                            />
               </div>)}
```

**Child Component**

```
export default class OverallProgressLineChart extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        courseWiseScoreDetailsOfAllExams: props.data,
        dataForSelectedCourse: {
            courseID: null,
            courseName: null,
            examNames: [],
            examScorePercentages: [],
            highestScore: 0,
            lowestScore: 0,
            averageScore: 0,
            examAttempted: 0
        }
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.updateDataForSelectedCourse(this.props.selectedCourseID);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.updateDataForSelectedCourse(nextProps.selectedCourseID);}    
  updateDataForSelectedCourse(selectedCourseID = null) {
    let newDataForSelectedCourse = null;
        if (this.state.courseWiseScoreDetailsOfAllExams.courseID === 
  selectedCourseID) {
     newDataForSelectedCourse = this.state.courseWiseScoreDetailsOfAllExams;
        }
  this.setState({dataForSelectedCourse: newDataForSelectedCourse}, function () {
        this.setChartData();
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to get the updated state in child when parent state got updated. Please someone review my code above and give me a solution

Comment: In your child component, when it instantiates, you're setting the state with props.data.  Initially this will be empty.  E.g. overallProgressData.  There's no provision in the child component to update itself based on changing values....

Comment: ... To me, it looks like you trying to manage the same state value at several levels in your app.  This is not a good approach.  State should be managed and updated in only one place.

Comment: ... Have a re-read of the React docs on their website.  You ought to find the 'highest' component in the page/app that contains all the children that you need to pass data to.  State should be managed in highest component and passed as props to the child components.  If you take this approach (again see React site), then changes to state will be propagated down to child components.

Comment: ...If one of the child components needs to update the state of something in a parent component, then this too can be achieved with React and is clearly explained in the React guide.

Comment: @Chris Adams I have select list with some option have a selectedCourseId. when the option changed selectedCourseId is changed and also props changed and axios.get called and fetch the data and update the `overallProgressData` state and i send this state to child component but first time my child component get the state when  page load but when i change my selectedCourseId `overallProgressData` got updated but state is not passed to child.

Comment: It will be passed down to the child, but the child component is not updating the state as there is no command to do so.  The component is built once and then re-rendered, so the code in the constructor is not called again.  Therefore, this line "courseWiseScoreDetailsOfAllExams: props.data" is not called in a set state after it is constructed the first time.  I notice you have a componentWillReceiveProps method.  But you not updating courseWiseScoreDetailsOfAllExams with the new props in there either.  Again, as I said before, managing the same piece of data as state in several layers is bad.

Comment: thank you . would you please explain where in my code i should change. I also changed in componentWillReceiveProps but i can not get exact result.
please help me to update the code. @Chris Adams

Comment: ...You really ought to revisit the React docs to understand how to manage state in a parent componet and pass changed state to child components as props.   This page  explicitly describes how to handle state and managing change of state at several layers.... https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Hi, I'm not re-writing the code for you.  Have a look at the React page I shared and give it a go.  Then re-ask the question if you're still stuck.

Comment: Ok thank you...i will inform you

Comment: Good man.  In short, anything that needs to be 'state' should be in a parent and passed down down as props to child components.  If one of the child components needs to affect state, then look at 'binding' an event handler in the parent and passing that to the child.  Again, it's all in that link.

Comment: @ChrisAdams thanks for the link, i tried from above link but my problem is different with the link provided. In my component i have no onchange() method to pass as a props. I need to reflect the update state through component lifecycle. How can i recieve the updated state in child component?